# magnetic field using solenoid but multiple layer winding?

Tags: soldering

how to make a solenoid multiple layers winding to produce a desired magnetic field? In that case, the normal solenoid formula(mu*n*i) will be valid or not?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please note that in most cases single or two line questions will be deleted, because they tend to provide little information on the problem. In this case the question seems clear enough but shows little prior research. A question like this can be improved by referring to other ressources you alredy have consulted and by using the formula editor to make formulas more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The formula still works but the magnetic coupling from the wire-turns to your core will be worse. It is quite normal to have multiple layers of wire-turns on a core.

In the typical transformer equivalent circuit this will present itself as a greater portion of series inductance.